# Smoothing values between limits

Tags: limits, statistics

I've a set of a set of data with values between -200 and 8000. I need to have them capped between 0 and 246 but so no data is lost.

I could just multiply them but I want it so the further the values is from 0, the more it would be lowered. So eg. 100 wouldn't be changed much but 8000 would be lowered a lot.

The data is mostly between -100 and 1000 but I want the larger spikes to be included too.

Is there some algorithm to this? The data is actually 2D but the values next to each other shouldn't have much difference.

Comment: So do you mean that you want some non-linear function applied to the values? Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to add $200$ to each of the values, and now you have a dataset from $0$ to $8200$. Then multiply all those values by $\frac{246}{8200}$, and ta-da, you have values only between $0$ and $246$. But then you wanted some non-linear effect, right? Well, that can be done in many ways ...

Comment: I think, as it stands currently, the problem is not uniquely defined. Please define how exatly you want the larger values to be scaled down more than the small values. Anyway, I interpret this as a non-linear function. Something like a logarithmic thing? Square root or power function? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I want something non-linear. The issue with your example is that really small values would basically disappear. I need have whole numbers and rounding them all to the closest integer would ruin the data.

Comment: Ahaa, okay. Well, currently you have $8200$ levels, and you are anyway going to squeeze that to $246$ levels, so I think a lot of accuracy is lost anyway.

Comment: Something logarithmic, yes. But I really don't know how to specify more than "logarithmic thing".

Comment: I know. But I don't care much of the accuracy of those larger values (+2000). But I don't want them to completely disappear, I still want to see the spiking.

Comment: Well, the best that I can suggest is something like a function
$$
f(x) = \frac{246}{\ln{2}} \ln \left( \frac{x+200}{8200} +1 \right)
$$
This function has the properties $f(-200)= 0$ and $f(8000)=246$, and it also has the logarithmic property, where it sort of tapers off when the numbers get larger. Does this satisfy you?

Comment: Another option (power function) would be
$$
f(x) = 246 \cdot \left( \frac{x+200}{8200} \right)^{\alpha}
$$
for some value of $\alpha$ (possibly $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$). Here, you can see how these functions look like : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hppwjzmvlv

Comment: Have you made any progress in this problem? Any comments?

Comment: The second option looks very promising but I haven't tried it in practice yet. Thanks a lot for you help!